# how to convert ^M$ newline from dos to unix (dos2unix didn't work)

Tags: bash, dos2unix

was trying to remove the erroneous newline characters generated from Windows.

```
$cat -e file.xml
foo^M$
bar$
$
hello world1$
hello world2$
```

where there should be "foobar" without any newlines in between while all the newlines should be retained. 
I know within emacs we could do replacement of "^M^J" with 'RET', but I have a huge file that I don't want to open it but only wanted to use command line to convert it.

I tried `dos2unix` but it only removed the "^M" part, still rendering a broken word/sentence. Also tried `tr -d '\r'` and `sed 's:^M$::g'` or `sed 's:^M$\n:\n:g'`, all didn't work. Anyone has an idea how to do it correctly?

Comment: Why is there no `$` in the output after `bar` line? is it any other whitespace character? Or is it just a typo?

Comment: @anishsane sorry it's a typo, and I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replicated your example file as:

```
$ cat -e so.txt
foo^M$
bar$
line2$
line3$
```

You can use Perl in 'gulp' mode to do:

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/\r\n//g' so.txt
foobar
line2
line3
```

The problem with using most line oriented approaches is the `\r\n` is read as a line.

---

You can do:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\r\n//' /tmp/so.txt
foobar
line2
line3
```

as well...

Comment: I assume this -0777 is to trigger the 'gulp' mode? If so, we shouldn't be doing that because I mentioned this is a huge file I need to process (>5GB). Anyway, your suggestion works but i'm a bit surprised that there is not command line tool that can handle this neatly.

Comment: Perl and you OS will handle a huge file intelligently even if it is a lot larger than the host memory. Try it.

Comment: i did and it gave me a segmentation fault error if adding -0777 on  CentOS 6, that's why I commented above

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
$ cat -e so.txt
foo^M$
bar$
line2$
line3$

$ awk 1 RS=$'\r\n' ORS= so.txt
foobar
line2
line3

$ awk 1 RS=$'\r\n' ORS= so.txt | cat -e # Just for verification
foobar$
line2$
line3$
```

It sets the record separator to `\r\n` & prints the records with `ORS=<empty string>`

Comment: Thanks for the snippet and explanations! This works!

Comment: Does it scale for huge file size as you want?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will work

```
sed -e 's/[\n\r]//g' old_file.txt > new_file.txt
```

will work

Comment: Won't this remove *all* newlines?

Comment: As per the question *without any newlines in between*

Comment: But the question also mentions "huge file"... I wonder if OP really wants his file as a single line.

Comment: @BenjaminW. - Perhaps ask the person asking the question. The answer is to solve the stated problem

Comment: yeah, I had the same impression on this proposal. Anyway I tried it and it didn't work

Comment: @galactica You should clarify what you want then, because the question implies exactly what this answer addresses.

Comment: @galactica Whatever the length of the first line in your file is, post `hexdump -C -n linelength + 10 yourfilename` (or the equivalent hexdump using whatever program you have available)